# Preventing "-Graphics-" Output from ListPlot[] Command

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

Whenever I try to create a Graphics object in a Mathematica notebook, the output is always "-Graphics-". I have searched and found [others who had similar problems](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/795243), but attempting to implement these fixes have not been successful.

The offending option seems to be the "CommandDefaultFormatTypes" "Output" option. Others have recommended changing this to "StandardForm". After I made this change, then ran the plotting command, the output was still the same- "-Graphics-".

I am running Mathematica Version 11.3 on Windows 10 on a Microsoft Surface Pro.

Though it might not be possible to diagnose the specific issue, perhaps a workaround that would allow the Graphics to be viewed?

**UPDATE:**

A temporary workaround is to select each cell that only displays "-Graphics-" and press "Shift+Ctrl+N"

This converts that cell to "StandardForm" and the Graphic appears. A long term solution that changes an apparently hidden setting is still desired.

Comment: What happens if you run ``Get["Version6`Graphics`"]; $DisplayFunction = Identity;`` first and try plotting again?

Comment: You should answer questions to make progress in this. You edited the post but ignored J.M.'s question.

Comment: @Szabolcs I appreciate that these forums are so meticulously monitored that you noticed I made an edit, but it also just feels kind of creepy. This was originally produced on a colleague's computer, and I was waiting for him to run the suggested command. Unfortunately, I used my computer to verify that the "OutputForm" option caused the problem he was seeing. Now my installation is experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less The result is still "-Graphics-".

Comment: The time of the last edit is prominently displayed and unanswered questions get regular views. I saw this more than once and I would have asked the same as J.M.

Comment: Try this: go to this directory, `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd"}]`. Quit Mathematica. Delete `init.m` (after having backed it up!). This will reset your Front End's settings.

Comment: Worked! Would you like to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) to reset things. Reproducing your situation:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {CommonDefaultFormatTypes,"Output"}] = "OutputForm";
```

Then:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

> -Graphics-

Fixing things:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {CommonDefaultFormatTypes,"Output"}] = "StandardForm";
```

Then:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in @Szabolcs comment, the init.m file was the cause of the problem. The most direct way to fix this problem is to open the directory with your init.m ( `SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "FrontEnd"}]`), quit Mathematica, open the init.m file with a program other than Mathematica, find the line with `CommonDefaultFormatTypes`, and change "OutputForm" to "StandardForm" (without quotes).